# get alphabatic list from numeric one

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I have to get the following list:

```
result = ['A','B','C','D','E']
```

In another case, I have list:

```
[1,2,3]
```

I have to get

```
['A','B','C']
```

How would you do it?

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = []
for i in [1, 2, 3]:
    A += chr(i + 64)
```

Or even faster:

```
B = [1, 2, 3]
A = [chr(i+64) for i in B]
```

Comment: could you explain chr(i + 64)

Comment: ASCII/UTF8 code for letter A is 65. `chr(1+64)` = `chr(65)` = `A`.

Comment: This is one instance where the C code end up as more readable than python because in C `'A'` is an integer with the correct value, not a string. So the C code would read `'A' + i`

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import string
>>> [string.ascii_uppercase[x - 1] for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Comment: could you tell me why x-1?

Comment: @just: Strings are 0-based, therefore 'A' is at index 0.

Comment: Because python lists are zero-based (`ascii_uppercase[0]` is `'A'`, `ascii_uppercase[1]` is `'B'`), but your mapping is one-based (you're mapping `1` to `'A'`, `2` to `'B'`).

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import operator
>>> import string
>>> operator.itemgetter(*[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])(' ' + string.ascii_uppercase)
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
```

(But don't *really* do it this way...)

Answer (score 3):

A solution that doesn't depend on other modules:

```
def to_letters(lst):
    return map(lambda x: chr(64+x), lst) # ascii code of 'A' is 65, 'B' is 66 etc

print to_letters([1, 2, 3]) # prints ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: Plain and elegant solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.ascii_uppercase`

```
>>> from string import ascii_uppercase
>>> l= []
>>> for i in mylist:
...     l.append(ascii_uppercase[i-1])
...     
... 
>>> l
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
>>>
```

or use simple `list comprehension`

```
>>> [ascii_uppercase[i-1] for i in mylist]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Comment: could you tell me meaning of i-1?

Comment: @just indexing start from 0 in python, `mylist=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `ascii_uppercase='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'` so what i need, to pick first 5 characters starting from 0 index so that `ascii_uppercase[0]`=`A` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chr function

```
>>> chr(96 + 1)
'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

just one liner and with out importing any modules:

```
ans = [chr(i + 64) for i in [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: What behavior do you expect when the input is greater than 26?